# How to use express middleware on router level

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to add a simple middleware function for every request on the router level.

The docs are stating:

> a middleware function with no mount path will be executed for every
> request to the router

In my application I have only one router with one endpoint that is listening for every request and I'm placing my middleware function above this endpoint, but the middleware never gets launched.

Express setup:

```
const initializeExpress = (): void => {
  const port = process.env.PORT;
  const app = express();
  app.use(helmet());
  app.use(express.json());
  app.use(cors());
  app.use('/api', Router);

  app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Listening for requests at http://localhost:${port}`);
  });
};
```

My router code:

```
const Router = express.Router();

Router.use((req, res, next) => {
  const token = req.header('authorization');
  if (!token) res.status(401).send({ message: 'Unauthorized' });

  const isAuthenticated = isAuthorized(token!);
  if (isAuthenticated) {
    next();
  } else {
    res.status(401).send({ message: 'Unauthorized' });
  }
});

Router.get(
  '/:arg1/:arg1Id?/:arg2?/:arg2Id?/:arg3?/:arg3Id?/:arg4?/:arg4Id?',
  async (req, res): Promise<void> => {
    const routeParams = filterRouteParams(req.params);
    const path = basePath + getPathFromRouteParams(routeParams) + '/data.json';
    if (await pathExists(path)) {
      const data = await getJsonFromPath(path);
      if (!isEmpty(data)) {
        res.status(200).json(data);
        return;
      }
      res.status(400).send({ message: 'Data not found' });
    }
  }
);
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Does it show any error? Or It is not going in the middleware function?

Comment: My GET route gets launched without calling the middleware, no error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On which route the middleware will be active, you need to define it.

There's two way to make this

First, call middleware before the your route:

```
const Router = express.Router();

const myMiddleware = (req, res, next) => {
  const token = req.header('authorization');
  if (!token) res.status(401).send({ message: 'Unauthorized' });

  const isAuthenticated = isAuthorized(token!);
  if (isAuthenticated) {
    next();
  } else {
    res.status(401).send({ message: 'Unauthorized' });
  }
}

Router.get(
  '/:arg1/:arg1Id?/:arg2?/:arg2Id?/:arg3?/:arg3Id?/:arg4?/:arg4Id?',
myMiddleware(), //Call middleware here 
  async (req, res): Promise<void> => {
    const routeParams = filterRouteParams(req.params);
    const path = basePath + getPathFromRouteParams(routeParams) + '/data.json';
    if (await pathExists(path)) {
      const data = await getJsonFromPath(path);
      if (!isEmpty(data)) {
        res.status(200).json(data);
        return;
      }
      res.status(400).send({ message: 'Data not found' });
    }
  }
);
```

Second, calling middleware for all routes that you define:

```
const Router = express.Router();

const myMiddleware = (req, res, next) => {
  const token = req.header('authorization');
  if (!token) res.status(401).send({ message: 'Unauthorized' });

  const isAuthenticated = isAuthorized(token!);
  if (isAuthenticated) {
    next();
  } else {
    res.status(401).send({ message: 'Unauthorized' });
  }
}

Router.use('/:arg1/:arg1Id?/:arg2?/:arg2Id?/:arg3?/:arg3Id?/:arg4?/:arg4Id?', myMiddleware());

Router.get(
  '/:arg1/:arg1Id?/:arg2?/:arg2Id?/:arg3?/:arg3Id?/:arg4?/:arg4Id?'
  async (req, res): Promise<void> => {
    const routeParams = filterRouteParams(req.params);
    const path = basePath + getPathFromRouteParams(routeParams) + '/data.json';
    if (await pathExists(path)) {
      const data = await getJsonFromPath(path);
      if (!isEmpty(data)) {
        res.status(200).json(data);
        return;
      }
      res.status(400).send({ message: 'Data not found' });
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: This is indeed a solution to my problem but is there no way I can assign a middleware to all my routes in this router with one assignment?

Comment: The second way I suggested doing exactly that. The address you use in `Router.use` and all its derivatives will get into middleware.